# Wall collision in a maze with line segment intersection

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, maze

I am trying to make a  sort of maze game based on something like this: https://tankstroubleunblocked.com/

I have a very big array containing the walls, where each wall has three elements: an x position, a y position, and a type. For example, the wall [13, 5, 1] Has a top left corner at (13, 5) and is vertical. Originally, I was going to use corners to detect collisions, but I realized that would not work in cases like this: [image: example] I'm now doing a collision system with line segment intersection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

However, I don't know how to move the tank away from the line. It's easy enough if I run into a wall head on - just stop the momentum in the direction of the wall. However, like in the case above, I am coming into the wall from one of its origin points. If it tries to stop my momentum by pushing me sideways, it will look like a glitch in-game, as what it really needs to do is push me backwards.

How do I fix this? Do I make a second, invisible wall on the end of every wall that ends like this? Is there an algorithm with angles? If I push the tank in the opposite direction, it will not move slightly sideways, like it is supposed to. What should I do?

Now that I am using code, I should tell you I am using the p5js library. Basically, what I want to know is what should I put in the wallCheck(arr) function? The array passed into it is the walls that it is going to test.

```js
var walls = [[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 1], [0, 5, 1], [0, 6, 1], [0, 7, 1], [0, 8, 1], [0, 9, 1], [0, 10, 1], [0, 11, 1], [0, 12, 1], [0, 13, 1], [0, 14, 1], [0, 15, 1], [0, 16, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 16, 0], [2, 0, 0], [2, 16, 0], [3, 0, 0], [3, 16, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 16, 0], [5, 0, 0], [5, 16, 0], [6, 0, 0], [6, 16, 0], [7, 0, 0], [7, 16, 0], [8, 0, 0], [8, 16, 0], [9, 0, 0], [9, 16, 0], [10, 0, 0], [10, 16, 0], [11, 0, 0], [11, 16, 0], [12, 0, 0], [12, 16, 0], [13, 0, 0], [13, 16, 0], [14, 0, 0], [14, 16, 0], [16, 0, 1], [15, 0, 0], [16, 1, 1], [16, 2, 1], [16, 3, 1], [16, 4, 1], [16, 5, 1], [16, 6, 1], [16, 7, 1], [16, 8, 1], [16, 9, 1], [16, 10, 1], [16, 11, 1], [16, 12, 1], [16, 13, 1], [16, 14, 1], [15, 16, 0], [16, 15, 1]], [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 0], [3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]], [[1, 5, 1], [1, 6, 1], [1, 7, 1], [1, 4, 0], [2, 4, 1], [2, 5, 1], [1, 7, 0], [3, 4, 1], [3, 6, 1], [2, 7, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 7, 0]], [[1, 8, 1], [0, 10, 0], [1, 11, 1], [2, 8, 1], [1, 9, 0], [1, 10, 0], [1, 11, 0], [3, 8, 1], [3, 9, 1], [2, 10, 0], [3, 10, 1], [3, 8, 0]], [[1, 13, 1], [1, 14, 1], [1, 12, 0], [2, 12, 1], [2, 13, 1], [1, 15, 0], [3, 12, 1], [2, 13, 0], [3, 14, 1], [2, 15, 0], [3, 12, 0], [3, 14, 0]], [[5, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [5, 3, 1], [6, 1, 1], [5, 2, 0], [6, 2, 1], [7, 0, 1], [6, 3, 0], [7, 3, 1], [7, 2, 0]], [[4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 0], [5, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [5, 4, 0], [6, 4, 1], [5, 6, 0], [6, 6, 1], [6, 5, 0], [7, 5, 1], [6, 7, 0], [7, 7, 1], [7, 6, 0]], [[4, 10, 1], [4, 11, 1], [5, 8, 1], [4, 9, 0], [5, 9, 1], [4, 11, 0], [6, 8, 1], [5, 10, 0], [6, 11, 1], [6, 9, 0], [7, 9, 1], [7, 10, 1], [7, 8, 0], [7, 9, 0], [7, 11, 0]], [[4, 13, 1], [4, 15, 1], [5, 12, 1], [4, 13, 0], [4, 14, 0], [5, 14, 1], [5, 12, 0], [6, 14, 1], [6, 13, 0], [7, 13, 1], [6, 14, 0], [7, 15, 1], [7, 12, 0], [7, 14, 0], [7, 15, 0]], [[8, 1, 1], [8, 2, 1], [8, 3, 1], [8, 2, 0], [9, 1, 0], [10, 2, 1], [9, 3, 0], [11, 0, 1], [10, 1, 0], [10, 3, 0], [11, 2, 0]], [[8, 4, 1], [8, 6, 1], [8, 4, 0], [9, 5, 1], [8, 6, 0], [9, 7, 1], [9, 4, 0], [10, 4, 1], [9, 6, 0], [9, 7, 0], [10, 7, 1], [11, 4, 1], [10, 5, 0], [11, 6, 1], [11, 4, 0], [11, 6, 0]], [[8, 8, 0], [9, 8, 1], [8, 10, 0], [8, 11, 0], [9, 11, 1], [10, 9, 1], [9, 10, 0], [10, 11, 1], [11, 8, 1], [10, 9, 0], [10, 10, 0], [11, 10, 1], [11, 9, 0]], [[8, 12, 1], [8, 13, 0], [8, 14, 0], [9, 14, 1], [10, 12, 1], [9, 13, 0], [9, 14, 0], [10, 15, 1], [10, 12, 0], [10, 14, 0], [11, 14, 1], [11, 13, 0]], [[12, 1, 1], [12, 2, 1], [13, 1, 1], [12, 3, 0], [14, 0, 1], [13, 2, 0], [13, 3, 0], [15, 1, 1], [14, 2, 0], [14, 3, 0], [15, 3, 1], [15, 2, 0]], [[12, 7, 1], [12, 4, 0], [12, 5, 0], [12, 6, 0], [13, 6, 1], [13, 4, 0], [13, 5, 0], [14, 5, 1], [13, 7, 0], [14, 4, 0], [14, 5, 0], [15, 6, 1], [14, 7, 0], [15, 7, 1], [15, 5, 0]], [[12, 10, 1], [12, 11, 1], [12, 8, 0], [12, 9, 0], [13, 9, 1], [13, 10, 1], [12, 11, 0], [13, 8, 0], [14, 8, 1], [14, 9, 1], [13, 11, 0], [14, 11, 1], [14, 9, 0], [15, 10, 1], [15, 11, 1], [15, 9, 0]], [[12, 12, 1], [12, 13, 1], [12, 15, 1], [13, 12, 1], [12, 14, 0], [12, 15, 0], [13, 13, 0], [14, 13, 1], [14, 14, 1], [13, 15, 0], [14, 12, 0], [15, 12, 1], [14, 14, 0], [15, 15, 0]]];
var size = 20;
var ratio;
var testPlayer;
var scaleup = 2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  testPlayer = new Player(15, 13, 0);
  ratio = width/height;
}

function draw() {
  background(210);
  // for(var i = 0; i < walls.length; i ++) {
  //   for(var j = 0; j < walls[i].length; j ++) {
  //     if (walls[i][j][2] === 0) {
  //       line(walls[i][j][0]*size, walls[i][j][1]*size, walls[i][j][0]*size+size, walls[i][j][1]*size);
  //     } else if (walls[i][j][2] === 1) {
  //       line(walls[i][j][0]*size, walls[i][j][1]*size, walls[i][j][0]*size, walls[i][j][1]*size+size);
  //     }
  //   }
  //   stroke(255, 0, 0);
  //   strokeWeight(5);
  //   point(testPlayer.pos.x*size, testPlayer.pos.y*size)
  //   stroke(0);
  //   strokeWeight(1);
  // }
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  scale(scaleup);
  translate(width/-2, height/-2)
  testPlayer.move();
  testPlayer.wallCheck([]);
  translate(width/2 + map(testPlayer.pos.x, 0, 16, 0, width)*-1, height/2 + map(testPlayer.pos.y, 0, 16, 0, height)*-1*ratio);
  scale(width/320, height*ratio/320);
  renderWalls(testPlayer.pos.x, testPlayer.pos.y/ratio);
  scale(320/width, 320/(height*ratio));
  testPlayer.show();
  translate(width/2 + map(testPlayer.pos.x, 0, 16, 0, width), height/2 + map(testPlayer.pos.y, 0, 16, 0, height)*ratio);
}

//renders walls lol
function renderWalls(posx, posy) {
  var renderedChunks = whichChunks(posx, posy);
  for(var i = 0; i < walls.length; i ++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < walls[i].length; j ++) {
      if (walls[i][j][2] === 0) {
        line(walls[i][j][0]*size, walls[i][j][1]*size, walls[i][j][0]*size + size, walls[i][j][1]*size);
      } else if (walls[i][j][2] === 1) {
        line(walls[i][j][0]*size, walls[i][j][1]*size, walls[i][j][0]*size, walls[i][j][1]*size+size);
      }
    }
  }
}

//which chunks are wall tested with a certain player position
function whichChunks(posx, posy) {
  var renderedChunks = [0];
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j ++) {
      if(posx > i * 4 - 1 && posx < i * 4 + 5 && posy > j * 4 - 1 && posy < j * 4 + 5) {
        renderedChunks.push(i * 4 + j + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return renderedChunks;
}

//test for line segment intersection for walls
function intersect(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
  var t = (((x1 - x3) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y3) * (x3 - x4))) / (((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)));
  var u = (((x1 - x3) * (y1 - y2)) - ((y1 - y3) * (x1 - x2))) / (((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)));

  var x = x1 + t * (x2 - x1);
  var y = y1 + t * (y2 - y1);

  return [x, y, t, u];
}

var corners = [];

class Player {
    constructor(x, y, dir) {
        this.pos = createVector(x, y);
        this.dir = dir;
        this.sizex = 0.25;
        this.sizey = 0.25;
    }

    move() {
            if(keyIsDown(37)) {
                this.dir -= Math.PI;
                if(this.dir < 0) {
                    this.dir += 360;
                }
            }
            if (keyIsDown(39)) {
                this.dir += Math.PI;
                if(this.dir > 360) {
                    this.dir -= 360;
                }
            }
            if (keyIsDown(38)) {
                var accel = createVector(cos(this.dir)*16/width, sin(this.dir)*16/height);
                accel.mult(Math.PI/3);
                accel.x *= ratio;
                this.pos.add(accel);
            }
            if(keyIsDown(40)) {
                var accel = createVector(cos(this.dir)*16/width, sin(this.dir)*16/height);
                accel.x *= ratio;
                this.pos.add(accel.mult(-1*Math.PI/3));
            }
    }

    show() {
        translate(map(this.pos.x, 0, 16, 0, width), map(this.pos.y, 0, 16, 0, height)*ratio);
        rotate(this.dir);
        fill(255)
        rect(0, 0, map(this.sizex, 0, 16, 0, width), map(this.sizey, 0, 16, 0, height)*ratio);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        rect(map(this.sizex, 0, 16, 0, width)/8*3, 0, map(this.sizex, 0, 16, 0, width)/4, map(this.sizey, 0, 16, 0, height));
        rotate(this.dir*-1)
        translate(map(this.pos.x, 0, 16, 0, width)*-1, map(this.pos.y, 0, 16, 0, height)*-1*ratio);

        for(var j = 0; j < corners.length; j ++) {
            translate(map(corners[j].x, 0, 16, 0, width), map(corners[j].y, 0, 16, 0, height)*ratio);
            stroke(255, 0, 0);
            strokeWeight(2);
            point(0, 0)
            strokeWeight(1);
            stroke(0);
            translate(map(corners[j].x, 0, 16, 0, width)*-1, map(corners[j].y, 0, 16, 0, height*ratio)*-1);
        }
    }

    wallCheck(arr) {
        corners = [createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir+45), sin(this.dir+45)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2)), createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir+135), sin(this.dir+135)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2)), createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir-135), sin(this.dir-135)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2)), createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir-45), sin(this.dir-45)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2))];

        for(var i = 0; i < corners.length; i ++) {
            if(corners[i].x > 15.99) {
                this.pos.x = this.pos.x - corners[i].x + 15.99
            }
            if(corners[i].y > 15.99) {
                this.pos.y = this.pos.y - corners[i].y + 15.99
            }
        }

        var chunksToRender = whichChunks(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);

        for(var i = 0; i < chunksToRender.length; i ++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < walls[chunksToRender[i]].length; j ++) {
                if(walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][2] === 0) {
                    var intersection = [intersect(walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0]+1, walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], corners[0].x, corners[0].y, corners[1].x, corners[1].y), intersect(walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0]+1, walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], corners[2].x, corners[2].y, corners[1].x, corners[1].y), intersect(walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0]+1, walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], corners[2].x, corners[2].y, corners[3].x, corners[3].y), intersect(walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][0]+1, walls[chunksToRender[i]][j][1], corners[0].x, corners[0].y, corners[3].x, corners[3].y)];
                    for(var k = 0; k < intersection.length; k ++) {
                        if (intersection[k][2] > 0 && intersection[k][3] > 0 && intersection[k][2] < 1 && intersection[k][3] < 1) {
                            
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        corners = [createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir+45), sin(this.dir+45)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2)), createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir+135), sin(this.dir+135)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2)), createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir-135), sin(this.dir-135)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2)), createVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).add(createVector(cos(this.dir-45), sin(this.dir-45)).mult(sqrt(2*(pow(this.sizex, 2)))/2))];

    }
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  canvas {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="player.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include a [mimimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can help you. There is very little to go on with no code provided.

Comment: I've done that now - I don't know how to remove code in a short time, so I tried to comment what most things do.